# Autoindent not working. Kinda weird Vim behavior

Tags: vim

So, I have this unit test file which has lot of tests inside the main test block. Basically a huge JSON.

I can do `=` in VIM to autoindent all the lines or based on blocks. Everything works fine, until...

If the inner block starts or/after line 2052, the autoindent will indent it as if it was outside of the enclosing block.

Example:

```
1| describe() {
2|   block_1() {
3| 
4|   }
5| }
```

This works.

```
   1| describe() {
    .
    .
    .
2052| block_1() {
2053| 
2054| }
2055| }
```

Whatever I do, the block_1() will be indented to left. I have to manually indent it.

Anyone found this?

This is on MAC High Sierra. I tried with vim and macvim.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't some unusual syntax element prior to line 2052 that might trip up indenting? Does this happen only with that file, or also other long ones? Without the (obfuscated) original file, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @IngoKarkat No syntax differences. I didn't try other files. But, moving the other lines up and down turns the behavior on and off. The block which is below 2052 stops working. If I move it to 2051 somehow, it works again.